# Curved interpolated transition between surface and upright circle

Tags: modeling, bezier-curves, interpolation

I'm trying to make an object consisting of a curved flat shape transitioning to an upright circle.
I already made some edges for the transition profile using curves.

[image]
[image]
[image]

If I convert those curves to a mesh, it kind of gives a feeling of how it should look, but the mesh is interpolated linear and not actually transitioning into the circle.

[image]

What can I do tho make it a smooth transition?
I had considered adding more curves and doing the transition by hand, but it kind of feels like I'm missing some tools that could make this a lot easier.

Any help is appreciated!

[.blend file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/18-96eK9ap-UcfqUd-YUYSvGqLZ2g3HPI/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I prepared a rectangle with evenly spaced vertices using the snap to vertex option, it resulted maden of 38 vertices, so i added a circle of 38 vertices in the appropriate location, and I used Bridge edge loops function to connect them.

Then I added a loopcut in the middle and adjusted scaling based on your curve, and added similarily other 2 edge loops.